# Laravel Add attribute to model in __constructor

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to add an attribute to my model so I can say something like: `$model->path` and then get back a url. So I've added the following to the model's constructor:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array()){

    $this->path = url('img/' . $this->{'file-name'});
    parent::__construct($attributes);

}
```

But if I run `Model::first()` then I get the following:

```
{
  id: 25,
  text: "A lovely file",
  file-name: "file.jpg",
  created_at: "2016-02-12 11:44:37",
  updated_at: "2016-02-12 11:44:37"
},
```

You'll notice that there is no `path` attribute. Am I doing something very wrong?! I want to see:

```
{
  id: 25,
  text: "A lovely file",
  file-name: "file.jpg",
  path: "http://myapp.app:8000/img/file.jpg",
  created_at: "2016-02-12 11:44:37",
  updated_at: "2016-02-12 11:44:37"
},
```

For the record, I have also tried `$this->field = 'value';` and that didn't create an attribute either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs). You’d be better off using an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

```
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return url('img/'.$this->file_name);
}
```

You also shouldn’t be using dashes in column/property names, use the convention of underscores for separators.

Comment: You'll also need the `$appends` property if the `path` attribute doesn't exist on the model or table. Hidden at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: That's great, thanks – and noted on the hyphen. Is there any way of including this attribute automatically, or am I best off doing something like: `$imgs = \App\Img::all(); foreach($imgs as $img){ $img->url = $img->path;`  – just so the collection I return for my API is formatted nicely?

Comment: @Djave As @Mysteryos says, you can add `path` to your `$appends` array and that’ll include the value in any serializing to JSON, arrays etc.